# How to add Response Card in Lex using PutIntent method?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I am trying to add a Response Card in lex using `putIntent()`. In AWS the `putIntent` method accepts `responseCard` as a String but how to add `title`, `subTitle`, `ImageUrl`, `button` values, and `button` names at the time of creating an Intent using response card parameter through `putIntent`?

So can anyone please help me to solve the issue. Provide a sample input where  response card as String which can contain the above attributes. Thank you in advance.

```
"slots": [
    {
        "description": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "priority": number,
        "responseCard": "string",
        "sampleUtterances": [ "string" ],
        "slotConstraint": "string",
        "slotType": "string",
        "slotTypeVersion": "string",
        "valueElicitationPrompt": {
        "maxAttempts": number,
        "messages": [
            {
                "content": "string",
                "contentType": "string",
                "groupNumber": number
            }
        ],
        "responseCard": "string" --(how to pass title, imageUrl and other attributes) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got the correct slots portion of the full response format from [Lex API PutIntent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_PutIntent.html).

The `responseCard` format can be found at [Lambda Input Response Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format)

```
"responseCard": {
  "version": integer-value,
  "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
  "genericAttachments": [
      {
         "title":"card-title",
         "subTitle":"card-sub-title",
         "imageUrl":"URL of the image to be shown",
         "attachmentLinkUrl":"URL of the attachment to be associated with the card",
         "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button-text",
                "value":"Value sent to server on button click"
             }
          ]
       } 
   ] 
}
```

Assuming you create that `responseCard` object in the format above as a variable named `responseCard`, then to make that object a string to pass in `PutIntent` try:

`JSON.stringify(responseCard)` if using Node.js, or
`json.dumps(responseCard, separators=(',',':'))` if using Python.

Comment: Thank You for your reply.  I already tried that approach but it didn't work. Not able to see response card in Amazon lex console for that particular prompt.

Comment: I see. You should definitely include in your questions what you have tried before and any code examples or any errors that occurred during those attempts. As far as I know, there is no other format for a responseCard to be passed as a string, so  I'd look at debugging your previous attempt of this. So I suggest editing your question to include that code and any errors or simply what occurred.

Comment: One thing to note is that the Amazon Lex console does not render response cards. It may be correct even though you cannot see it there.

Comment: Thats actually not true. Lex console does render response cards but you have to provide an image URL (which is not actually required to get a response card object). It's just a bit buggy unfortunately.